# Number of path to soccer game score

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to figure out the number of paths possible for a soccer match, given the end score of each team:

For example:

If each team scored 2 goals:

(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (1,2) (2,2)

(0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (2,1) (2,2)

(0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (1,2) (2,2)

(0,0) (1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (2,2)

(0,0) (1,0) (1,1) (2,1) (2,2)

(0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (2,1) (2,2)

Note: the end score does not have to be the same for both teams.

I think that every time a team scores, there are two options: either one team scores or the other. So the result should be even. but I could not find the solution myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think that every time a any team scores, there are two options, either one team scores or the other, so the result should be even.

That isn't true.  For instance, when your score is 0-2 in a game that eventually ends 2-2, the last two goals can only be by one of the teams.

---

If one team ends the game with $x$ goals and the other team gets $y$ goals, then we need essentially need to choose which of the $x+y$ goals in order were scored by the first team.  This number is ${x+y}\choose x$.